# Entity Framework Code First: How can I create a One-to-Many for this relationships?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

so Iam new to code firt and I have a database that is done already and cant change and I get this error when I call clientes in my controller get this error because it look for a Empresa_id that not exist so how I can tell to look for the the correct field?

```
return View(clientes.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

it return this select 
SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[empresa] AS [empresa],  
[Extent1].[Empresa_id] AS [Empresa_id]
FROM [dbo].[cliente] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[name] ASC}


public class cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int empresa { get; set; } // foreing key

        public virtual empresa Empresa { get; set; }
   }

    public class empresa
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string descripcion { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You should really read something about naming conventions. Having two public properties which differ only by casing of the first character is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell EF that `empresa` is the foreign key for the navigation property `Empresa`, otherwise it will assume a default foreign key name, that is "NavigationPropertyName+UnderScore+KeyNameInTargetClass" = `Empresa_id`. You can overwrite this default by applying the `[ForeignKey]` attribute:

```
public class cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Empresa")]
    public int empresa { get; set; }

    public virtual empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```